# WSL able to touch file but mkdir: Permission denied

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am relaying my ssh connection and I want to restrict the ability of the remote user to view my files so I set `umask = 027`. However, it seems to also affect the local user in some way as I can no longer `mkdir` as the local user using either

```
mkdir test
```

or

```
sudo mkdir test
```

both yield `Permission denied` error
However, I can

```
touch test
```

with no problem. I have checked that ownership of the current folder is the local user logged into wsl.